# How do I apply SHA-1 to a large hex number byte by byte?

Tags: java, sha

I'm trying to create a program that will enable me to convert a MEID (a hex number of length 14) to pseudo ESN (a hex number of length 8). The way to obtain a pESN from MEID is fairly simple in theory. For example, given MEID 0xA0000000002329, to make a pESN, SHA-1 needs to be applied to the MEID. SHA-1 on A0000000002329 gives e3be267a2cd5c861f3c7ea4224df829a3551f1ab. Take the last 6 hex numbers of this result, and append it to 0x80 - the result is 0x8051F1AB.

Now here is the code I have so far:

```
public void sha1() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {

    String hexMEID = "A0000000002329";

    MessageDigest mDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA1");      
    byte[] b = new BigInteger(hexMEID,16).toByteArray();    

    byte[] result = mDigest.digest(b);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        sb.append(Integer.toString((result[i] & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1));
    }

    System.out.println(sb.toString());
}
```

The problem is that using this method, SHA-1 on A0000000002329 gives 6ad447f040941bf43c0693d2b391c6c79fa58320 instead of e3be267a2cd5c861f3c7ea4224df829a3551f1ab. What am I doing wrong here??

Someone gave me a hint that

> The trick is to apply SHA-1 to the number representing the MEID, not
>   the string representing the MEID. **You'll need to process it
>   byte-by-byte, so you must give it two hex numbers at a time (since two
>   hex numbers make a byte) and make sure they are interpreted as numbers
>   and not ASCII characters**.

If these instructions are true, then how do I apply SHA-1 to my hex number byte by byte??

Comment: "two hex numbers make a byte"?

Comment: @aviad, of course. 0xff == 255 (or 16x16-1, or 2^8-1, or 8 bits) which is a byte

Comment: @Yanick Rochon, i would rather say: "1 byte is required to represent 2-digits hexadecimal number"...

Comment: @aviad, ... or "two hex digits represent a byte", it's the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strelok has found the problem about `BigInteger` adding an extra byte in the returned array. This simpler version also gives the expected result :

```
String hexMEID = "A0000000002329";

MessageDigest mDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA1");

byte[] b = new BigInteger(hexMEID,16).toByteArray();

// skip the first byte set by BigInteger and retain only 7 bytes (length of MEID)
byte[] result = mDigest.digest(Arrays.copyOfRange(b, 1, 8));

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("80");

// need only the last 3 bytes
for (int i=17; i<20; i++) {
    sb.append(Integer.toHexString((result[i] & 0xff) | 0x100).substring(1));
}

String pESN = sb.toString();
System.out.println(pESN);
// -> 8051f1ab
```

Answer (score 4):

You have a tiny little issue which is the consequence of using `BigInteger` to get your byte array. Since the MEID is only 7 bytes long, when you pump it through the BigInteger, you will get a byte array of length 8 because the BigInteger outputs the exta byte which holds the sign. This extra byte causes the SHA-1 hash of your input to be completely different, of course. You need to strip it off.

So here is what the HEX MEID to ESN code will look like:

```
String hexMEID = "A0000000002329";
MessageDigest mDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance( "SHA1" );

byte[] input = new byte[ 7 ]; // MEIDs are only 7 bytes

// Now copy the bytes from BigInteger skipping the extra byte added by it
System.arraycopy( new BigInteger( hexMEID, 16 ).toByteArray(), 1, input, 0, 7 );

// Get the SHA-1 bytes
byte[] result = mDigest.digest( input );

// Build the SHA-1 String
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for ( int i = 0; i < result.length; i++ )
{
    String hex = Integer.toHexString( 0xFF & result[ i ] );
    if ( hex.length() == 1 )
    {
        sb.append( '0' );
    }
    sb.append( hex );
}

String sha1 = sb.toString();
// Grab the last 6 characters of the SHA-1 hash
String lastSix = sha1.substring( sha1.length() - 6 );
// And prepend '80', now you have the ESN
System.out.println( "80" + lastSix );
// Will print 8051f1ab which is exactly what you want
```